# Injectivity checking of $ ( T- \mu I)|_{G_{\lambda}(T) }$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Suppose that $\lambda $ and $\mu $ are distinct eigenvalues of T.

Prove that $ ( T- \mu I)|_{G_{\lambda}(T) }$ is injective.

assume that $( T- \mu I)|_{G_{\lambda}(T) } v = ( T- \mu I)|_{G_{\lambda}(T) } u $

$u,v \in G_{\lambda} (T) \implies u-v \in G_{\lambda} (T) $

$$\implies( T- \mu I)|_{G_{\lambda}(T) } u = ( T- \mu I) u= ( T- \mu I) v $$
So we have that  $( T- \mu I) (u-v)=0 \implies u-v \in E_{\mu } \subset G_{\mu}$

Since $T(u-v) = \mu ( u-v) \implies u-v=0 \implies u=v \implies$ one to one.

I am alittle leery about a couple of the steps  is this actually correct?

Comment: How are $E_\mu$ and $G_\mu$ defined?

Comment: They are the Eigenspace and generalized eigenspace of $\mu $